# z direction of a matrix in a GLSL shader

Tags: glsl

I have the following (working) code in a GLSL shader:

```
vec3 normal = vec3(u_mvMatrix * vec4(0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0));//normal in eye space (no scaling in u_mvMatrix).
```

However, since what I need is just the z direction of the u_mvMatrix, which of the following lines is equivalent to the line above:

```
vec3 normal = u_mvMatrix[2].xyz;
```

or:

```
vec3 normal = vec3(u_mvMatrix[0].z,u_mvMatrix[1].z,u_mvMatrix[2].z);
```

?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: @Krister Andersson: I've just added a question mark to make the question clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenGL matrices are column-major by *default*.

You can make them row-major in GLSL with a layout qualifier (e.g. `layout (row_major) uniform mat4 u_mvMatrix;`). Note that pre-multiplication of a row-major matrix is the same as post-multiplication of a column-major matrix, so this is a true statement:

`(mat * vec) == (vec * transpose (mat))`

In the fixed-function pipeline when OpenGL does a matrix multiply, it is always column-major and post-multiplied. Direct3D is row-major and pre-multiplied. In the programmable pipeline you have full control over the matrix notation and whether you pre- or post-multiply.

Getting back to your question, in this example you are post-multiplying (the matrix is on the l-hand side of the `*` operator) a column-major matrix. The correct equivalence is therefore `vec3 normal = u_mvMatrix [2].xyz;`

For a lengthy article that does a decent job explaining what I just wrote, see [this site](http://seanmiddleditch.com/journal/2012/08/matrices-handedness-pre-and-post-multiplication-row-vs-column-major-and-notations/).